# Cannot undertsand the message of git , after taking an older version of code and creating a new branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

I took an older version of code using --
I issued the following commands--

- `$ git checkout 3d2aae898d734e14b8f0abdfd7c40e06dce38442`

**Git message--**

```
Note: switching to '3d2aae898d734e14b8f0abdfd7c40e06dce38442'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at 3d2aae8 Arpan Banerjee-Added login/signUp,loading spinner with firebase
```

- git checkout -b "develop_old"

**Git message--**

```
Switched to a new branch 'develop_old'
```

I issued the following command to see whats my origin pointing to-

- git remote -v

**Git Output--**

```
origin  https://github.com/navindian/AngularPhotoGallery.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/navindian/AngularPhotoGallery.git (push)
```

- git branch -a

**Git Output--**

```
* develop_old
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/dependabot/npm_and_yarn/bootstrap-3.4.1
  remotes/origin/master
```

Can someone pls explain me what does the output say---
The head should point to my newly created branch right? But instead it is pointing to the master branch.

But there is a `*` in front of `develop_old` branch , that means I am at the branch now?

So , now if I make any changes and commit? To which branch will it be committed?

Comment: I think this is because you didn't put anything in your branch, try making some small change and committing, I think it will then point to your expected branch.

Comment: I committed a new change, the branch got created, but still the head points to the same. :(

Comment: on second thought there is no reason your remote should point to your newly created branch you just created a new branch you did not change where the remote points to!
See here (or just search SO) how to change it: https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-a-remotes-url

Comment: No, this `git remote set-url` is used to point to diff repositories, here I am working within the same branch.

Comment: I don't think you understand, each branch has it's. own url, you simply created a new local branch, it is not even a remote branch, you need to A. create a new remote branch (one on your repo) and B. Point your "origin" to that branch.

Comment: Okay, so after I have pushed some changes to my newly created `develop_old` branch, a remote branch will be created right. Now if i want to point the head to that branch i need to use `set-url`? Or `git commit -u origin develop_old`?

Comment: Should, but you still need to point your head at it if you want it to be where you push to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213033/discussion-between-arpan-banerjee-and-michael).

Answer (score 1):

Your current branch is `develop_old` (the star besides the name on `git branch -a`. You have another local branch called `master` and the other branches are your current knowledge of those remote branches.

Comment: Okay. Can you pls explain what do u mean by `your current knowledge of those remote branches` in terms of git.

Comment: A remote repo is a different repo from your own.... you `sync` with it when you do pull/fetch. If you ran those operations last time 2 months ago, you won't know about revisions/branches on that remote repo since. If you ask to run `git branch -a` or ` git log --all` you will see old information on that repo. That.'s what I mean.

Comment: So, to push a new commit how do i set my head to the newly created branch? if i simply issue push request to which branch will it be pushed to? pls ans to these two questions.

Comment: In git, HEAD is always where you are (in svn it has a very different meaning). If you run `git push` without saying anything else, it won't push anywhere (while working on `develop_old`) because of the way you created `develop_old`. Right now the branch is not tracking any remote branch.

Comment: so i need to issue either of the following commands if i want to push it to `develop_old` branch--`git remote set-url` of `git push --u origin develop_old`? right?